# JavaFX Running WebEngine in another thread than FX Application Thread

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine, javafx-webview

As I stated in the title, is it possible to run [WebEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#loadContent-java.lang.String-) in another thread than FX Application Thread?

**Code:**

```
...
WebEngine webEngine = new WebEngine();

Thread thread = new Thread(() -> 
    webEngine.load("https://www.google.com"));
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
...
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-6
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.checkThread(WebEngine.java:1243)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.load(WebEngine.java:913)
    at sample.Main.lambda$start$0(Main.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You already got your answer yourself... it seems?
Anyways, `WebEngine::load()` is asynchronous, though you must call from JavaFX Application Thread.

Comment: Do you want to tell us why you want to do that? Afaik the web engine starts another thread for loading stuff, anyway.

Comment: In my application, when a user clicks something for example, application is supposed to redirect user to a website and execute some JS code on browser based on user's input. What I wanted is keeping WebEngine already loaded on the backgroud and when user clicks, show browser and execute JS code. Obviously, this would be much faster.

Comment: @MertAkozcan just call it from the fx application thread, load the page and only add it to the scene when the user clicks

Comment: Loading in "another thread" does not solve this problem at all. Loading a web page *is slow*, there is no magic to make it load instantly. The only way is to anticipate the need to load a webpage, and pre-load it way before you need it. You can always not show the `WebView` until you need to show it. Yes, this method is going to cost you memory and processing if you make a wrong "guess."

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) it's not possible.

> WebEngine objects must be created and accessed solely from the JavaFX
>   Application thread. This rule also applies to any DOM and JavaScript
>   objects obtained from the WebEngine object.